# How get icon from url and set to windowIcon

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyside2

When I try to set my icon from url which contain favicon.ico it work fine, but when I try to set my icon from url which contain **.jpg or .png ** format it does not work  and return none. Kindly help me to solve the problem.

you can check the following code.

```
 
 # url = "http://www.google.com/favicon.icon
         
 url = 'http://www.geo.tv/assets/front/images/gn-icons/256x256.jpg'
 self.nam.finished.connect(self.finishRequest)
 self.nam.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)))
 



def finishRequest(self,reply):
        img = QImage()
        
        img.loadFromData(reply.readAll())
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(img))
```

I want to get url of image(png,jpg) mean url of icon of a website. and set to a label, windowIcon etc.
but it works only with image(.ico) format and does not work with other format and return nothing.

Comment: Use QPixmap, not QImage.

Comment: Both not working I have tried. Both work only for .ico format

Comment: Then either the image is not properly downloaded, or there is some issue with your Qt installation, as it's probably missing the image plugins for the icon engine. Does setting those images as icons work if you load the file locally? What is the result of `print(img.loadFromData(reply.readAll()))`? And that of `QImageReader.supportedImageFormats()`?

Comment: its print **True** only.

Answer (score 2):

Analyzing the url I have seen that redirection from http to https so the reply does not have the bytes of the image but the following url. One possible solution is to have Qt handle redirects using `request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest.FollowRedirectsAttribute, True)`.

```py
import sys
from functools import cached_property

from PySide2.QtCore import Signal, QObject, Qt, QUrl
from PySide2.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap, QIcon
from PySide2.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkReply, QNetworkRequest
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


class ImageDownloader(QObject):
    finished = Signal(QImage)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.manager.finished.connect(self.handle_finished)

    @cached_property
    def manager(self):
        return QNetworkAccessManager()

    def start_download(self, url):
        request = QNetworkRequest(url)
        request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest.FollowRedirectsAttribute, True)
        self.manager.get(request)

    def handle_finished(self, reply):
        if reply.error() != QNetworkReply.NoError:
            print("error: ", reply.errorString())
            return
        image = QImage()
        ok = image.loadFromData(reply.readAll())
        if not ok:
            print("error")
            return
        self.finished.emit(image)


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.downloader = ImageDownloader()
        self.downloader.finished.connect(self.handle_finished)
        url = QUrl("http://www.geo.tv/assets/front/images/gn-icons/256x256.jpg")
        self.downloader.start_download(url)

        self.resize(640, 480)

    def handle_finished(self, image):
        pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(pixmap))


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!..... But I **don't want to download**, I wanna to get icon from url **online** and show them in a tab... just like a *browser tab* has website icon...

Comment: @JawadHussainShah See the update

Comment: show an error: **qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted: TLS initialization failed
error:  TLS initialization failed**

Comment: @JawadHussainShah If you are on windows you must install OpenSSL